# Accessing data from table using relationship in laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I have these tables
**users**:id name
**posts**:post_id,post,user_id
**comments**:comment_id,Comment,post_id

My relation in maodel is

**User model**

```
public function posts()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('Post','post_id');
   }
```

**post model**

```
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('User','post_id');
}

public function comments()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('Comments','comment_id');
  }
```

**comment model**

```
public function post()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('Post','comment_id');
 }
```

i'm accessing post's comments using

```
 $comments = Post::find(1)->comments;  But its giving an error.
```

please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments();
```

You're not calling your function, you forgot the brackets.